# Passing dynamically created form fields to PHP

Tags: php, javascript, html, forms

I am trying to pass dynamically created form fields to a php script, and it's causing me a huge headache.

I've done this in the past many times, and I can't figure out what i'm doing wrong here.

Below is an example of what's going on:

A brief explanation: I have a form with a textarea, there is a button named "Add More", when clicked, a new textarea is generated via javascript. The textareas values are pushed into an array named "comments". When I try to loop through this array within my php script, it only gives me the first item, and none of the dynamically created ones.

HTML

```
<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" accept-charset="utf-8">
<textarea name="comments[]"></textarea>
<a href="javascript: return null;" class="add-more">Add More</a>
</form>
```

JS

```
$(".add-more").click(function(){ 

       var new_field = '<textarea name="comments[]"></textarea>';
       $(this).before(new_field);

});
```

PHP - this is where the issue is, when I try to loop through the comments[] array, it only gives me the first one, and does not bring through any of the ones that were generated dynamically.

```
<?php

$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$commentString = "";
foreach($comments as $value) {
$commentString .= $value;
}

?>
```

So with the above, if I create 5 textareas using the "Add More" button, input some text into each one, and then submit the form, none of the dynamically created fields send through to the php.

Can anyone help?

Thanks!!

Comment: How are you submitting the form?

Comment: I'm submitting the form using the url of the page the form is on, within the file there is a php script that catches the post variables, you can see part of it above.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This has been resolved.

The issue was being caused by an unclosed form above the one I was having the issues with.

Thanks for the replies everyone!

Comment: @Kristian there is a time-block on makring your own answer as correct on your own question. (48 hours from memory)

Answer (score 4):

`<form action="" method="post" />`

should be:

`<form action="" method="post">`

Answer (score 0):

The other answer is correct, but you also will need to close the form as well.  Your code was missing the closing ">" as well.

```
<form action="" method="post" >
<textarea name="comments[]"></textarea>
<a href="javascript: return null;" class="add-more">Add More</a>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

Also, the class name in your JS didn't match the class name in your HTML.

Here it is all together and working:

```
<html>

<head>

<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

<form action="" method="post">

    <textarea name="comments[]"></textarea>

    <a href="javascript: return null;" class="add-more">Add More</a>

    <input type="submit" />

</form>

<script>
    $(".add-more").click(function(){ 
           var new_field = '<textarea name="comments[]"></textarea>';
           $(this).before(new_field);

    });
</script>

<?php

$comments = $_POST['comments'];

$commentString = "";

foreach($comments as $value) {
    $commentString .= $value;
}

echo $commentString;

?>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Thanks for the replies guys, everything that was mentioned is actually correct in my code. I was in a rush when I posted the question.

The question has been corrected with the actual syntax.